# Gradient boosting and feature to target correlations?

Tags: correlation, boosting, autoencoders

I'm working on a data science challenge, I have a tabular data with around 80 features (79 predictors and a target variable between 0 and 1).

I've tried two approaches:

- Using autoencoders to do reduce the number of features to 20 and reduce noise too .... (1)
- Using manual feature selection by inspecting feature importances and domain knowledge....(2)

For each approach, I'm using a gradient boosting machine, "lightGBM", I got an RMSE of 0.093 using the first approach and an RMSE of 0.095 (between 0.095-0.10) using the 2nd approach.

At first, I thought that the autoencoder helped me achieve a better score by reducing the noise in the data (which is quite noisy). Then I checked for the correlations between these new features created by the autoencoder and the target y and I was shocked that the highest correlated feature was only around 0.3 which is quite low compared to the 2nd approach where I had features highly correlated with y (0.7 and 0.6). This seems counterintuitive, I checked Spearman and Pearson correlations for the autoencoded feature and they are both quite low.

Is this normal? Or is correlation not informative about the performance of gradient boosting machines? I need to understand why to choose an approach and fine-tune it further.